# I water bath’d my freezer cherry jam

Tags: canning

I water bath my freezer jam. I didn’t realize I was using freezer pectin. Can I make this jam shelf safe at this point?

Comment: pectin is pectin, whether for freezer or shelf. The issue is how much of it you use. So you could open the jars, boil it up with more pectin, and re-process it, but I suspect it would be less effort to just freeze it.

Comment: @KateGregory The issue is not the amount of pectin - you don't need pectin for canning at all, it is just there because some people prefer the texture of jam made with pectin. The issue is whether the jam can safely be canned, and this depends on the recipe.

Comment: fruit brings its own pectin to the game. Many freezer jams are little more than cooked fruit with some sugar. Shelf stable jams have a gel to them which is made of sugar and pectin, whether that's from the fruit or because you added some. I personally don't add pectin to my jams, but I don't think that means they don't have any.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a proper cherry jam recipe, made to be water bath canned, but just used the wrong pectin, then your jam will be safe, however your jam may never set.